# Сделать запрос на создание определенного количества строк в таблице

Tags: sql, ms-access

У меня есть таблица Продукты (p_id,p_name,p_count) и Екземпляры(e_id(тип данных счетчик), product_id)

У каждого продукта может быть много экземпляров. У разных экземпляров может быть одинаковый product_id, но e_id Всегда разный.

Я хочу сделать запрос, чтобы в Екземпляре строки заполнялись автоматически, если количество экземпляров с product_id меньше, чем  p_count.

То есть, если, например  p_count = 3, p_id = 1, а экземпляров с таким p_id нет, то сгенерируются следующие строки:

| e_id | product_code |
| --- | --- |
| ... | ... |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 7 | 1 |
| ... | ... |

(Работаю в Access)

Comment: *Я хочу сделать запрос* Да делайте, кто бы против... А вопрос-то собственно какой? в чём **конкретная** проблема? PS. Описанная операция по идее должна выполняться в VBA-коде при вставке или изменении записи в таблице `Продукты`. Можно также создать и отдельную процедуру, выполняющую указанную операцию.

Comment: Вопрос - как это сделать, я не силен в SQL. Запрос который мне нужен я описал, что тут непонятного может быть я не знаю:)

Comment: Запрос самый обычный - INSERT INTO. А поскольку MS Access не подозревает о существовании рекурсивных CTE и прочих вкусностей жизни - то выполняешь его из VBA кода столько раз, сколько нужно. Не, можно программно составить один запрос на вставку любого количества записей - но я лично противник подобного подхода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот запрос, который позволит понять, сколько раз надо вставить каждую запись в `Екземпляры`:

```sql
SELECT t1.p_id, t1.p_count needed, COUNT(*) present
FROM Продукты t1
LEFT JOIN Екземпляры t2 ON t1.p_id = t2.product_id
GROUP BY t1.p_id, t1.p_count
HAVING needed > present;
```

Запрос возвращает для каждого продукта количество записей, как требуемое, так и имеющееся, причём только для тех продуктов, для которых необходимо добавить ещё записей.

А дальше - обрабатывай полученный набор и вставляй.

Альтернативно - просто вставляем каждого продукта по одной записи. После чего снова выполняем запрос. И повторяем, пока после очередной итерации запрос не вернёт пустой набор записей. Ещё разумнее сразу преобразовать этот SELECT в INSERT, и повторять пока количество вставленных записей не станет нулевым.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Из любопытства попробовал вставить несколько недостающих записей одним запросом

```
INSERT INTO Examples
SELECT t.p_id 
FROM(
  SELECT p.p_id,p.p_name,p.p_count
    ,(select count(*) from Examples e where e.p_id=p.p_id) as cnt   ,nn.n
  FROM Product as p 
   ,(select top 1 1 as n from Product 
     union select top 1 2 as n from Product
     union select top 1 3 as n from Product 
     union select top 1 4 as n from Product) as nn 
 ) t
where t.n>t.cnt and t.n<=t.p_count
;
```

В Access работает.